# SQL Stored procedure Joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

**Background:** My problem is a little specific.  I am following a spec to create a application and one of the tasks involves creating a stored procedure.  I know how to create and store a procedure as well as implement one, but I am just having trouble with some syntax of constructing one.

The spec states:

**Write a stored procedure upGetTestID. It will accept 3 parameters: WOID, SampleID , Analyte
    You need to join tblWOSampleTest to tblTest on TestID
    Then SELECT TestID WHERE the three values match**

I am having trouble understanding what I am supposed to do. The tables need to be joined because one table has columns WOID, SampleID, TestID but no Analyte, while the other table only has Analyte and TestID.  But then I don't know how to  *SELECT TestID WHERE the three values match* Here are some attempts to replicate the instructions:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upGetTestID @WOID nvarchar(60), @SampleID nvarchar(60),@Analyte nvarchar(60)
AS

SELECT TestID
FROM tblWOSampleTest
JOIN tblTest
ON tblTest.TestID=tblWOSampleTest.TestID; 
WHERE @WOID = tblTest.WOID AND @SampleID = tblTest.SampleID AND @Analyte = tblTest.Analyte

GO
```

This did not work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upGetTestID @WOID nvarchar(60), @SampleID nvarchar(60),@Analyte nvarchar(60)
AS

SELECT *
FROM tblWOSampleTest
JOIN tblTest
ON tblTest.TestID=tblWOSampleTest.TestID; 

SELECT TestID
WHERE @WOID = tblWOSampleTest.WOID AND @SampleID = tblWOSampleTest.SampleID AND @Analyte = tblTest.Analyte

GO
```

This also didn't work.  What I really want to know is what the instructions want me to do because I am a little confused on that.

Answer (score 0):

You where should be against the tables that have the required columns. Otherwise your first post was the right way.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upGetTestID @WOID nvarchar(60), @SampleID nvarchar(60),@Analyte nvarchar(60)
AS

SELECT TestID
FROM tblWOSampleTest
JOIN tblTest
ON tblTest.TestID=tblWOSampleTest.TestID; 
WHERE @WOID = tblWOSampleTest.WOID AND @SampleID = tblWOSampleTest.SampleID AND @Analyte = tblTest.Analyte

GO
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but it says there is an error near WHERE

Comment: Not sure which of your tables had what fields but your join is good. Then your WHERE should ask for the values in the tables that have the fields you want. If you need more help, I need to see the schema of the 2 tables. I can only guess from you post right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upGetTestIDForAnalyte @WOID nvarchar(60), @SampleID nvarchar(60),@Analyte nvarchar(60)
AS

SELECT TestID = t1.TestID
FROM tblWOSampleTest t1
JOIN tblTest t2
ON t1.TestID=t2.TestID; 
WHERE @WOID = t1.WOID AND @SampleID = t1.SampleID AND @Analyte = t2.Analyte

GO
```

My issue turned out to be an ambiguous column name.  I used this website as a reference http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-does-ambiguous-column-name-mean.html.  I needed to specify which table was being used for the column TestID